# Objdump - How to output text (eg ASCII strings) alongside assembly code?

Tags: disassembly, disassemblers, binary, objdump, hexadecimal

Aim: I want to take hex and ascii data (derived from a binary file using xxd) and use Objdump (or a suitable other tool that Linux comes with) to output the memory addresses / offsets, assembly code, and text data.

Currently I can get the offsets and assembly code, but not text strings alongside.

I used the following:
`objdump -D -b binary -mi386 -Maddr16,data16 <filename>`

Should I need to use the `-s` switch?

Comment: Are you analyzing data from binaries that conform to a particular ABI or format (ELF, COFF, MACHO, etc)?

Comment: You will need a tool like IDA to automatically determine what is data and code in your binary.

Comment: I can't use IDA at this moment. I am looking for manual methods or those that come with common Linux distributions.

Comment: Some py scripts by iirc dion mendel in the old honeynet sotm reversing challenges  used objdump and could beautify the deadlisting here is a link to a tut that adapts them to analyze a simple binary see if that helps ( the contents concepts and thevinevitable assumptions are old so you may need a pitcher full of salt nearby )  http://www.reversing.be/article.php?story=2005030218170966

Comment: @blabb the site you linked in previous comment is blacklisted by Firefox. Any other page you know?

Comment: Well i dont know the site is clean afaik and i am the author of the linked article search for sotm reversing challenges maybe

Answer (score 35):

It is assumed here that Linux ELF32 binaries are being analyzed.

Code and data such as strings are stored in separate parts of ELF binaries.

- To disassemble the parts containing code, use `objdump -dj .text <binary_name>`.
- To examine hard-coded string data, use `readelf -x .rodata <binary_name>`

#### Instructions and Data are located in separate areas within ELF binaries

> Currently I can get the offsets and assembly code, but not text strings alongside.

Code and hardcoded strings are not intermingled in x86 or x86-64 ELF binaries. When the compiler toolchain generates a binary, hardcoded strings are placed in a separate area of the binary from the executable code and are referenced/accessed by their virtual memory address. Here is a [diagram](https://github.com/corkami/pics/raw/master/binary/elf101/elf101.pdf) by Ange Albertini of the how different sections are laid out in ELF binaries:
       [image: Ange Albertini ELF]

To make this more clear, below are visualizations of the Linux utilities `ls`, `cat`, `mkdir` and `mv` (accomplished via [binvis.io](http://binvis.io/#/)). The solid blue areas consist of ASCII string data (the `.rodata` section, for example), and the large blocks of blue, white, red and black mixed together are regions that consist of executable code (the `.text` section, for example).

`*       ls                  cat              mkdir                mv`

[image: ls]
[image: cat]
[image: mkdir]
[image: mv]

As we can see from these visualizations, these binaries are organized in a similar fashion. Each binary has discrete areas, or sections, which contain different information. We can also see here that there are multiple areas (i.e. sections) containing ASCII string data, not just one.

Sections with executable instructions will not contain meaningful strings, only code. This can be observed directly by using the `-s` option with `objdump` when examining the `.text` section of the Linux `date` utility:

```
$ objdump -sj .text /bin/date
/bin/date:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .text:
 401af0 41574531 ff415645 31f64155 41544531  AWE1.AVE1.AUATE1
 401b00 e45589fd 534889f3 4881ecd8 00000048  .U..SH..H......H
 401b10 8b3ee8f9 530000be a1c84000 bf060000  .>..S.....@.....
 401b20 00e8bafe ffffbe87 944000bf 61944000  .........@..a.@.
 401b30 e83bfcff ffbf6194 4000e811 fcffffbf  .;....a.@.......
 401b40 102c4000 e8877800 00c64424 0f0048c7  .,@...x...D$..H.
 < snip >
```

In ELF binaries, the `.text` section holds the executable instructions of the program. The bytes the instructions are composed of are being treated as ASCII in this hexdump, so there are meaningless sequences of characters being printed.

#### Objdump will treat data as instructions and disassemble accordingly

`objdump` relies on an ELF binary's section headers to determine which sections of the binary contain code and which sections contain data. Only sections with instructions (`.text`, for example) should be disassembled using `objdump`.The `-D` argument to `objdump` will result in all sections of an ELF binary being disassembled, even non-code sections like `.data` and `.rodata`.

From the manual page:

> -D
>
> --disassemble-all
>
> Like -d, but disassemble the contents of all sections, not just those expected to contain instructions.

This means that even if a section contained hardcoded strings (`.dynstr`, `.shstrtab`, `.rodata`, etc.) `objdump` would treat this data as instructions and dissasemble them accordingly.

Here is an example using /bin/date:

```
/bin/date:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .rodata:

0000000000409400 <.rodata>:
  409400:       01 00                   add    %eax,(%rax)
  409402:       02 00                   add    (%rax),%al
  409404:       74 69                   je     40946f <__sprintf_chk@plt+0x798f>
  409406:       6d                      insl   (%dx),%es:(%rdi)
  409407:       65 20 25 73 20 69 73    and    %ah,%gs:0x73692073(%rip)        # 73a9b481 <stderr+0x7348d131>
  40940e:       20 6f 75                and    %ch,0x75(%rdi)
  409411:       74 20                   je     409433 <__sprintf_chk@plt+0x7953>
  409413:       6f                      outsl  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  409414:       66                      data16
  409415:       20 72 61                and    %dh,0x61(%rdx)
  409418:       6e                      outsb  %ds:(%rsi),(%dx)
  409419:       67 65 00 0a             add    %cl,%gs:(%edx)
  40941d:       52                      push   %rdx
  40941e:       65                      gs
  40941f:       70 6f                   jo     409490 <__sprintf_chk@plt+0x79b0>
  < snip >
```

It looks like there are instructions being disassembled, when in reality is data being treated as code:

```
$ readelf -x .rodata /bin/date
Hex dump of section '.rodata':
  0x00409400 01000200 74696d65 20257320 6973206f ....time %s is o
  0x00409410 7574206f 66207261 6e676500 0a526570 ut of range..Rep
```

Furthermore, the arguments `-b binary` result in `objdump` treating the binary as a blob with a single section, obliterating any distinction between code and data within the binary, resulting in the entire contents of the binary being treated as code.

Reference: the [System V ABI](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/gabi41.pdf) section 4: "Object Files"

Comment: Ok, so what syntax should I use for just disassembling the code sections using `objdump`?

Comment: objdump -d <file name>. The -d option results in only the sections expected to contain code to be disassembled.

Comment: In fact, read-only strings may be present in code sections too, especially on embedded platforms like ARM or MIPS

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I have never heard of this. Would a tool like `objdump` be able to distinguish between read-only strings and instructions in code sections? Can read-only strings be found in executable sections of ELF binaries?  The OP did not specify what kinds of binaries he is trying to analyze so I assumed Linux x86 ELF. What changes should I make in my answer to make it correct? If my answer cannot be salvaged should I delete it?

Comment: ARM linker can add [special symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM-Mapping-Symbols.html) like `$d` to mark data areas in code sections (though I think these are mostly used for jump tables and such) but I don't know if objdump makes use of them. Your answer is fine for the common case, you can just mention your assumptions at the beginning.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky I edited the answer. Thank you for the correction and the link to the relevant information

Comment: Ok thanks. How about names of functions in the binary - do they get into the hex data when using xxd? If yes, how can you identify them from the assembly code?

Comment: @unseen_rider a hexdump of an unstripped binary will include the contents of the `.strtab` section. This section contains strings corresponding to the symbols in the binary's symbol table (`.symtab`). Among these strings there will be function names. If the binary is dynamically linked then this holds true for the `.dynstr` section as well. The `.dynstr` section will be present in a dynamically linked binary even if the binary is stripped.

Comment: one thing to note in -D disassemble all mode, is that strings in .rodata will resemble hard-to-read / gibberish instructions. if you examine these instructions in detail they will indeed make no sense.

Comment: What about macOS? How can I view the text strings in a macOS executable binary file? There's no `readelf` (but there is `objdump`).